# Plural Form Name for tables problem in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4, propel

I use database that has been created by someone else and I can't change it. Database uses plural form for its tables' names. In my symfony application I use Propel as ORM. I wanted to change tables' names using phpName attribute in my schema.yml but it works for model only. Forms and filters have wrong (automatically generated) names.

Here is my schema.yml:

`AgentServices:
    _attributes: { phpName: AgentService }
...`

In lib\model I have:

```
AgentService.php and AgentServicePeer.php (this is correct)
```

but in lib/form I have:

`AgentservicesForm.class.php`

Any suggestions what to do in this case?

Thanks

Comment: Any reason to pick a plural name?

Comment: Yes. There is an existing application that uses it. Database has been created by other programmer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,

I've recreated the project and built everything from scratch. It worked. I can't explain it though. It wasn't surely a cache issue because I was clering it plenty of times. Strange thing.